# Files that I pase in external hard drive are not there. and sum of folders in drive is way less than the drive's size

Tags: windows-8.1, external-hard-drive

I wanted to transfer some files to my pc, so I connected my external hard drive to another pc and transfered 8 .rar parts with "send to...".(my hard drive was not empty at first.) now when I connect it to my pc there isn't any file there except :

$RECYCLE.BIN (701 MB)

autorun (7.74 bytes)

System Volume Information (hidden folder) (0 byte)

3 of .rar files (part 3 - part 4 - part 5) (each of them is 1 GB)

I tried to cut these 3 .rar files to my computer but an error occurred and just one of them pasted there. (part 3)

but when I click on driver's properties, 82.2 GB of it's space is used. so i think some files are still there but some how they are hidden. I checked "show hidden files, folders, and drives" and unchecked "hide empty drives" , "Hide extensions for known file types" , "hide folder merge conflict" and "hide protected operating system files (Recommended)".
I have windows 8.1
I don't really know how can i recover my files?

[image]

Comment: We need more information.  Can you run `WinDirStat` as an Administrator on the drive in question and provide a screenshot uploaded to imgur?  You should take the time to properly format your question.

Comment: **autorun (7.74 bytes)**: fractional  bytes? Can you state 1) how many bytes you think you copied to the drive (6GB? 82GB?), 2) the filesystem of the drive (FAT32? NTFS? Other)? and if you followed the appropriate procedure to disconnect the drive from the first computer?

Comment: @xenoid autorun size : 7934 bytes and size on disk : 12288 bytes. 1) about 8 to 10 GB I think but my hard drive wasn't empty at first as I mentioned. 2) NTFS. do you mean safe to remove hardware or something? my cousin disconnected the drive and I don't know for sure but I think he didn't.

Comment: @bhmoh When you copy huge files on the disk, better check that all the disk are copied, and use the safe removal that ensures that all the necessary I/O is performed. So time to do it again it seems.

Comment: So what does Disk Mangement think the size of the drive is?  Something has changed the partition size to 2.7GB

Answer (score -1):

Sounds like you may have purchased one of those crappy thumb-drives from ebay.  There was a rash of thumb-drives that were actually 1-2gb... where the firmware would loop the drive and falsely report a larger available drive than there was.  Every tool you would use to look at the drive would report 8+gb... but it really wasn't.  As long as you don't go over the actual size of the drive... you'd never know.  Once you try to go over that size, the old stuff would get overwritten causing lots of corruption, and other weird symptoms.

Comment: my hard drive is WD 1tb portable external hard drive.

Comment: I don't know maybe it is. but why there wasn't an error while copying? and can I recover my files or I should give up?

Comment: When was the last time you did a full disk scan?  It sounds like you may have a drive that has bad sectors, and might fail at any time.

Comment: ... you can download the WD "Data Lifeguard Diagnostics" from here: https://support.wdc.com/downloads.aspx?lang=en ... that will do the drive diagnostics, and provide you with all the details you might need.

Comment: it passed the test.